# Define a function which accepts two n-length arrays as argument and return matrix multiplication of arrays as output

Tags: javascript, typescript

Can anyone help with this question?

Define a function which accepts two n-length arrays as argument and return
matrix multiplication of arrays as output. Note that you must follow the rules of matrix
multiplication.
Example: consider

> A = [[8,3], [2,4], [3,6]], B = [[1,2,3], [4,6,8]].

The A × B output is

> [[20,34,48], [18,28,38], [27,42,57]]

Note. Matrix row length is equal to array length, and matrix column length is equal to array
items length. For example, the array A has three rows and two columns or A is a 3 × 2 matrix.

Helper docs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem?

Comment: see also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: There are plenty of 'JavaScript matrix multiplication' questions to look at on SO if you are stuck.

Comment: this is one of my tasks for the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we validate that

- the parameters are arrays
- the number of columns in A matches the number of rows in B
- the number of rows in A matches the number of columns in B

and then we do the actual calculation.

```js
function multiplicate(A, B) {
    if (!(Array.isArray(A) && Array.isArray(B))) throw 'You need to pass arrays';
    for (let row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
        if (A[row].length !== B.length) throw 'The number of columns in A needs to match the number of rows in B';
    }
    for (let column = 0; column < B.length; column++) {
        if (B[column].length !== A.length) throw 'The number of rows in A needs to match the number of columns in B';
    }
    let C = [];
    for (let row = 0; row < A.length; row++) {
        let newRow = [];
        for (let column = 0; column < A.length; column++) {
            let sum = 0;
            for (let k = 0; k < A[row].length; k++) {
                sum += A[row][k] * B[k][column];
            }
            newRow.push(sum);
        }
        C.push(newRow);
    }
    return C;
}

console.log(multiplicate(
     [[8,3], [2,4], [3,6]],
     [[1,2,3], [4,6,8]]
));
```

Comment: it's quite natural to use Fortran for this kind stuff, but still, the question is about javascript, not Fortran. ;)

Comment: @gog the answer was written in Javascript.